# Обработка нажатия на каждый пункт Listview

Tags: java, android-studio

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста есть как бы главная activity, на ней компонент listview как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первый элемент открывалась - вторая активити, при нажатии на второй - третья и так далее.
**код первой активити:**

```
  package com.example.admin.orshagoes; 

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.Toast; 


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

String [] array; 
ListView listView; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names); 

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); 

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array); 

listView.setAdapter(adapter); 


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 




@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, number_1.class); 
i.putExtra("position", position); 
startActivity(i); 

//startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, number_1.class)); 
} 
}); 
} 
}
```

**код второй активити:**

```
package com.example.admin.orshagoes; 

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity { 

String [] arr; 
ListView listView1; 
//int key = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0); 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); 


arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1); 
listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1); 

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr); 

listView1.setAdapter(adapter); 

} 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
int id = item.getItemId(); 
if (id == android.R.id.home) { 
finish(); 
} 
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял код, но по сути должно работать.

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    switch(position) {
        case 0: 
            startActivity(new Intent(this, your_activity1.class));
        break;
        case 1: 
            startActivity(new Intent(this, your_activity2.class));
        break;
    }
}
```